# How to use syntethic properties when you have the same layout included twice

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions

Normally, when I need to include the same layout in one screen, I would wrap this layout in two different containers with a different id and call `findViewById` on those two parents but I don't know if and how I could achieve the same result with kotlin's `syntethic` properties. Just to be more clear:

I am in the situation where **fragment_xyz.xml** is composed like this:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include layout="@layout/item_detail" />
  </FrameLayout>

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <include layout="@layout/item_detail" />
  </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**item_detail.xml**'content is similar to the following:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/description"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I would like to access those **title** and **description** with the usual:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_detail.*
```

But I need to distinguish between the one inside FrameLayout **include1** and FrameLayout **include2**

Thanks in advance!

Edit: typos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need import: 
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_xyz.*`

Then get the title and description from `framelayout` `include1` and `include2` like below:

```
val title1 by lazy {
    include1.title
}

val description1 by lazy {
    include1.description
}
val title2 by lazy {
    include2.title
}

val description2 by lazy {
    include2.description
}
```

Comment: This solution is only valid if fragment is never affected by any backstack or visbility changes, if it ever has it's view recreated then lazy fields are going to leak previous layout.